# How can I write vault encryped string »as is« to a file without being ask for the vault password?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-vault

Within a playbook I am created a key pair. I want to store both keys. To do that I want to encrypt them using ansible vault. So the playbook look like that:

```
- name: Generate ECDSA Keypair
  openssh_keypair:
    path: "{{ ssh_key_file }}"
    type: ecdsa
    size: 521
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Encrypt Keys
  ansible.builtin.template:
    dest: "{{ ssh_key_file ~ '.yml' }}"
    src: ../templates/dump.j2
  vars:
    private: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', ssh_key_file, rstrip=True) }}"
    public: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', ssh_key_file ~ '.pub') }}"
    content: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/key-pair.yml.j2') }}"
    data: "{{ content | ansible.builtin.vault('***') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

But running that fails:

```
fatal: [10.11.12.13 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "A vault password or secret must be
 specified to decrypt /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-3958nmbhie77/tmp4sausqh1/dump.j2"}
```

So ansible is asking me for the vault password to decrypt the string before rendering in the template. **BUT** I would love to store is encrypted for security reasons. How can I disable decryption for that task?

**UPDATE**
Content of `dump.j2`

```
{{ data  }}
```

**UPDATE #2**
The documentation for the above can be found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vault_filter.html#examples

Comment: And so, now, what is `content` where is this defined, what does it contains? (I guess a vault encrypted data, then, if I follow the question properly)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε it's defined in the `vars` like that: ` content: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/key-pair.yml.j2') }}"`

Comment: `data: "{{ content | ansible.builtin.vault('***') }}"` is where the final encryption happens

Comment: What happens if your _dump.j2_ file reads  `{{ content | ansible.builtin.vault('***') }}` rather than `{{ data }}`, then?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε same result

Comment: Could I suggest to rewrite your question in more minimal way ([mre]). I can reproduce with simply this: https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/a23bced528e4e6068689a8ebb2bf9960

Comment: Might not be totally useful but this is the reason: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/vault_using_encrypted_content.html#when-are-encrypted-files-made-visible

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [@β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%CE%B2-%CE%B5%CE%B7%CE%BF%CE%B9%CF%84-%CE%B2%CE%B5), whose comment linked directly to the root of the [issue](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/vault_using_encrypted_content.html#when-are-encrypted-files-made-visible):

> […] However, there is one exception. If you pass an encrypted file as the src argument to the copy, template, unarchive, script or assemble module, the file will not be encrypted on the target host […]

What happened is the intended and documented behaviour. Since I have tried to use a »vaulted« source withing the `ansible.builtin.template` module, the module tried to »un-vault« the value before rendering it.

To work around that I needed to use a different module to print the plain value, which I have achieved using this:

```
 - name: Encrypt Keys
   ansible.builtin.shell:
     cmd: echo '{{ data }}' > {{ ssh_key_file ~ '.yml' }}
     creates: "{{ ssh_key_file ~ '.yml' }}"
   vars:
     private: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', ssh_key_file, rstrip=True) }}"
     public: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', ssh_key_file ~ '.pub') }}"
     content: "{{ lookup('template', '../templates/key-pair.yml.j2') }}"
     data: "{{ content | ansible.builtin.vault(vaultpw) }}"
   delegate_to: localhost
```

Please note that this wont work on Windows and comes with all the disadvantages of using the `ansible.builtin.shell` module. So the general solution is: Do not use the: »copy, template, unarchive, script or assemble« module if you want to print / render encrypted values. The one that fits depends on the setup.